# Asymptotic behaviour of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, infinity

Could anyone explain in details how these approximations as $n \to \infty$ are found? ($a$ is a positive real number)

1. ${x_n} = \frac{1}{n}\left( {\frac{a}{3} - \frac{3}{2}} \right) + O\left( {\frac{1}{{{n^3}}}} \right)$ for ${x_n} = \sqrt[3]{{{n^3} + an}} - \sqrt {{n^2} + 3} $
2. ${y_n} = \frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{{n^{\frac{a}{2}}}}} - \frac{1}{{2{n^{\frac{{3a}}{2}}}}} + o\left( {\frac{1}{{{n^{\frac{{3a}}{2}}}}}} \right)$ for ${y_n} = \frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{\sqrt {{n^a} + {{( - 1)}^n}} }}$

The idea is to study the behaviour of a series whose $n-$th term is given by the above expressions in terms of the positive real $a$ and these asymptotic developments which I don't understand are part of the solution.

Comment: The meat of it is Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^\alpha$ around $x  = 0$. Do you know the Taylor expansion of that?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, but how can we adapt it to obtain an approximation near $+ \infty$ ?

Comment: If $n\to \infty$, then $1/n\to 0$. Use this fact in combination with factorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\sqrt[3]{n^3+an}=n\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{a}{n^2}}$.  We expand the latter using [Newton's Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) to get $$\sqrt[3]{n^3+an}=n\sum_{k\ge 0} {1/3 \choose k} \left(\frac{a}{n^2}\right)^k=n(1+\frac{a}{3n^2}-\frac{a^2}{9n^4}+O(n^{-6}))$$

Repeating, we have $\sqrt{n^2+3}=n\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{n^2}}$, so 
$$\sqrt{n^2+3}=n\sum_{k\ge 0}{1/2 \choose k}\left(\frac{3}{n^2}\right)^k=n(1+\frac{3}{2n^2}-\frac{3^2}{8n^4}+O(n^{-6}))$$

Subtracting, we get $$\sqrt[3]{n^3+an}-\sqrt{n^2+3}=n\left(\frac{a}{3n^2}-\frac{3}{2n^2}-\frac{a^2}{9n^4}+\frac{9}{8n^4}+O(n^{-6})\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! Pulling out that $n^3$ was the missing puzzle.

Comment: You're welcome, my pleasure.